# multiple section contexts in document which each has its own counter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, counters

I try to create a latex template for a homework where I need two section counters running parallel.

I have an example here:

[image]

As you can see I'd like to separate the main article from the administrative stuff by using roman and arabic counting.

Section 4 continues counting as there was no "Main Section" before with its own counting. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E.! Please post a MWE with your code.

Comment: With your example numbers of sections end with a dot while numbers of subsections do not. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @UlrichDiez No that is not intended. I've just put together a quick example to clarify how the counting should work. I assume the formatting can be adjusted later, once I understand how to create the different counting contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`:

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false]{scrartcl}% needs version 3.39 or newer

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\sectionnumdepth,
  beforeskip=-3.5ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  afterskip=2.3ex plus .2ex,
  indent=0pt,
  font=\usekomafont{section},
  tocstyle=section,
  toclevel=\sectiontocdepth,
  tocindent=0pt,
  tocnumwidth=1.5em,
  tocdynnumwidth,
  tocentryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry}
]{mysection}
\renewcommand\themysection{\Roman{mysection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\mysection{Section 1}
\mysection{Section 2}
\mysection{Section 3}
\section{Main Section 1}
\subsection{Main Subsection 1}
\subsection{Main Subsection 2}
\mysection{Section 4}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much!!! It seems I need to look further into scrartcl :)

Answer (score 1):

If using the documentclass book, you might consider using the commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` that come along with that documentclass.

Here is an example using the article class where "infrastructure" for maintaining the section-counter is maintained twice which makes it possible to switch between numbering styles and continuing numbering for each numbering style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{administrativesection}
\renewcommand\theadministrativesection{\Roman{section}}
\let\theHadministrativesection\theadministrativesection
%
\newcommand\c@mainsection{}%
\let\c@mainsection=\c@section
%
\newcommand\themainsection{}%
\let\themainsection=\thesection
%
\newcommand\theHmainsection{}%
\let\theHmainsection=\theHsection
%
\newcommand\mainsectioning{%
  \let\c@section=\c@mainsection
  \let\thesection=\themainsection
  \let\theHsection=\theHmainsection
}%
\newcommand\administrativesectioning{%
  \let\c@section=\c@administrativesection
  \let\thesection=\theadministrativesection
  \let\theHsection=\theHadministrativesection
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\administrativesectioning
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}

\mainsectioning
\section{Main Section 1}
\subsection{Main Subsection 1}
\subsection{Main Subsection 2}
\section{Main Section 2}

\administrativesectioning
\section{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats actually a great Idea too. I could still use the standard section commands but switching context when needed and not breaking anything else (like header, footer creation)